CORS Policy Issue When Making Fetch Call to Azure Service from Next.js App
I'm developing a Next.js application and am encountering a CORS policy issue when trying to make a fetch call directly to the Azure Cognitive Search service from my client-side code. I need to call Azure services directly using fetch and can't route the calls through a Next.js API route
Current Approach:
I'm making a fetch call like this:
fetch('https://ai-search-service-dev-basic.search.windows.net/datasources/samplel?api-version=2020-06-30', {
  method: 'POST', 
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'api-key': 'NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_SEARCH_ADMIN_KEY', 
  },
  // other settings...
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));

Constraints:
I understand the security implications and the typical approach to solving CORS issues by proxying through a server-side endpoint, but due to specific project requirements, I am looking for a way to directly call the Azure service from the client-side.
Modifying the server configuration to allow CORS from Azure is not an option.
The application is structured in such a way that using Next.js API routes to proxy these requests is not feasible.
Question:
If setting the request's mode to 'no-cors' is the only solution, what are the implications, and how can I handle the opaque response?

You write: I am looking for a way to directly call the Azure service from the client-side. Modifying the server configuration to allow CORS from Azure is not an option. But if the server isn't configured for CORS, you won't be able to consume its resources from the client side.
